# Usage of "(un) tant soit peu"

Tags: expressions, usage

> Je suis heureux de lui ressembler **un tant soit peu** !
>
> {or}: Je suis heureux de lui ressembler **tant soit peu** !

Is it more common to use the nominal phrase "un tant soit peu" than the adverbial version "tant soit peu" in this instance?

I also wonder if "(un) tant soit peu" always carries a negative/pejorative connotation? Which would make its use in this context odd.

Answer (score 2):

`un tant soit peu` could be replaced by `au moins un peu` ("at least a little bit"). I would not say it carries more than what it means.

'`tant soit peu`' w/o the '`un`' sounds strange and is never used, it would rather be equivalent to '`si peu`' ("so little").

Comment: *Is never used* is exaggerate, you can state it is rarer but not *never used*.

Comment: @jlliagre - do you have any example of its usage?

Comment: It is unclear if you state that the expression *tant soit peu* is never used without *un*, or that it wouldn't be used without *un* in the sentence *...lui ressembler [un] tant soit peu*.

Comment: what is not clear in "tant soit peu w/o the un is never used"?

Comment: Okay, your sentence is clear but its statement is incorrect. While the form without *un* is getting rarer and rarer since the end of the 20th century, there are still examples of *[tant soit peu](http://gabrielwyler.com/page233.html#tantsoitpeu,untantsoitpeu)* used without an article. A random but recent example: "*[Une scénographie ludique et évolutive au service d’un évènement fun, pédagogique et **tant soit peu politique**...](http://www.via.fr/evenements-expo-nouvelles-vies)*"

Comment: et tant soit peu politique [plus adjectif]; ressembler à quelqu'un un tant soi  peu [accompagne un verbe].

Answer (score 0):

I speak as a french native speaker so don't take this for 100% true but in general "un tant soit peu" is used for little quantities so if you're talking about ressemblance it should be "tant soit peu".

Answer (score 0):

L'expression

> Un tant soit peu

Signifie "Ne serait-ce qu'un petit peu", cela désigne effectivement une petite quantité.

Son deuxième sens, bien que très proche du premier serait "Si peu que cela soit" (so slightly en anglais).

L'expression est toujours utilisée avec l'article indéfini **un**

La plupart du temps cette expression est négative, par exemple :

> Je souhaiterai que tu sois un tant soit peu plus attentif à l'école

Comment: Le plus souvent utilisée avec *un*, mais pas *toujours*.

Comment: @jilliagre Je ne connais aucun exemple ou il est utilisé sans "un"

Comment: Voir mon dernier commentaire dans l'autre réponse.