# Chasser l’obscurité (un) tant soit peu

Tags: expressions, articles

> Les éclairs du feu de camp dansent sur nos visages en chassant
> l’obscurité **un** tant soit peu.

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28483/usage-of-un-tant-soit-peu), il serait possible d'omettre "un" devant "tant" et le sens de la phrase resterait le même. Est-ce correct ?

Comment: Larousse: Tant soit peu, un tant soit peu, en aussi faible quantité que ce soit, à un degré infime.

Comment: @Lambie Merci, j'ai vu cette définition, mais quelqu'un m'a dit que ces deux expressions ne signifient pas la même chose. Du coup, je ne sais plus quoi penser.

Comment: « S'il est (un) tant soit peu délicat, il comprendra » Comme le Robert, j'utiliserais le *un* dans cet exemple, comme je l'ajouterais dans le premier du cnrtl (il s'agit aussi d'une personne) : « *(Un) tant soit peu*. Si peu que ce soit. Si l'on est (un) tant soit peu critique, on est obligé de se dire en même temps que cela est impossible (Renan, Avenir sc., 1890, p. 329). Le seul moyen précis en effet de créer de la musique à partir d'objets sonores tant soit peu compliqués, c'est le montage(Schaeffer, Rech. mus. concr., 1952, p. 186) » un peu moins dans le second qui concerne des objets.

Comment: @Personne Merci. Donc, _un tant soit peu_ et _tant soit peu_ sont synonymes ? Ils sont interchangeables dans ma phrase ? Je suis du même avis que vous au sujet des "recompenses", mais vous pourriez rédiger des réponses, je pense, sans en tenir compte.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+tant+soit+peu%2Ctant+soit+peu&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20tant%20soit%20peu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctant%20soit%20peu%3B%2Cc0 J'ai vraiment l'impression que sans le *un*, c'est une écriture soutenue du millénaire passé, alors que j'ai toujours entendu le *un* à l'oral … sa récente remontée dans *ngram* va dans ce sens.

Comment: Mes commentaires sont libres de droit ( CC-BY-SA :-), on peut donc les inclure dans les réponses.

Answer (score 1):

***Un tant soit peu*** est proche des expressions plus courantes ***un tout petit peu*** et ***un minimum***.

***Tant soit peu*** est plus rare, il est toujours suivi d'un adjectif.

Ici ***un tant soit peu*** est une locution adverbiale qui modifie *chasser l'obscurité* (qui chasse un minimum l'obscurité)

> Les éclairs du feu de camp dansent sur nos visages en chassant l’obscurité **un tant soit peu**.

[...] en chassant plus ou moins l'obscurité

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peu) donne ces exemples :

> *Il suffit de réfléchir **un tant soit peu*** (Villiers de L'I.-A., *Contes cruels*, 1883, p. 68).

Il suffit de réfléchir un minimum.

> Ivresse publique **tant soit peu** déshonorante (Bloy, Journal,1893, p. 93).

Ivresse publique si peu que ce soit déshonorante.

Dans cette dernière phrase, l'auteur aurait aussi pu utiliser ***un tant soit peu** déshonorante*.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas, dans ma phrase, il n'y a pas d'adjectif avant _tant soit peu_. _Tant soit peu_ devrait être un adverbe, non ? Et _un tant soit peu_ un nom ? Ou aussi un adverbe ?

Comment: J'ai remanié ma réponse. L'adjectif doit être placé après *tant soit peu* (sans *un* donc).

Comment: Entendu il y a longtemps de personnes cultivées nées au début du XX°  : « Il est crétin, et c'est tant soit peu de le dire ! », plus tard ce sera « … et c'est pas rien de le dire ».